# Create Array going over List of Lists

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have multiple lists (6+) and have created a list of lists. The first element (lst1) should be paired with itself (lst1), then the second element(lst2), then the third(lst3), etc.  After finishing comparing against itself, it should move on to lst2 and compare to lst1, to lst2, lst3, etc. and produce an array (in the example, it would be a 6x6 array).  I'm not sure how to set up the for loop to do this.  I tried using a list as an output instead, but it doesn't work...should I be using some type of recursion instead?  If so, please help me get started there, since I'm not sure how to get there.

```py
lst1 = ['0.319', '0.277', '0.273', '0.240']
lst2 = ['0.037', '0.028', '0.026', '0.024']
lst3 = ['1.000', '1.000', '0.498', '0.495']
lst4 = ['0.319', '0.400', '0.273', '0.240']
lst5 = ['0.032', '0.028', '0.261', '0.024']
lst6 = ['0.75', '1.000', '0.498', '0.495']

lstoflsts = [lst1, lst2, lst3, lst4, lst5, lst6]

def jaccard_set(list1, list2):
    intersection = len(list(set(list1).intersection(list2)))
    union = (len(list1) + len(list2)) - intersection
    return float(intersection) / union

outputarray = np.empty((len(lstoflsts),len(lstoflsts))). #format of output
outputlst = []

for i in range(len(lstoflsts)):
    while i <= max(range(len(lstoflsts))):
        res = jaccard_set(lstoflsts[i], lstoflsts[i+1])
        outputlst.append(res)
```

Output results for first 2 loops:

```
[(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.6, 0.0, 0.0),
 (0.0, 1.0, 0.0 , 0.0 , 0.33, 0.0),
 .... ]
```

The output should be a 6x6 array:
jaccard_set(lst1,lst1), jaccard_set(lst1,lst2), jaccard_set(lst1,lst3), jaccard_set(lst1,lst4) jaccard_set(lst1,lst5), jaccard_set(lst1, lst6), jaccard_set(lst2,lst1), jaccard_set(lst2, lst2), jaccard_set(lst2, lst3) and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner while loop is unnecessary and will cause an IndexError when `i` is equal to `len(lstoflsts)-1`. You can remove the while loop and replace the `i+1` with `j` in the `jaccard_set` function call.

Here is the correct implementation

```py
import numpy as np

lst1 = ['0.319', '0.277', '0.273', '0.240']
lst2 = ['0.037', '0.028', '0.026', '0.024']
lst3 = ['1.000', '1.000', '0.498', '0.495']
lst4 = ['0.319', '0.400', '0.273', '0.240']
lst5 = ['0.032', '0.028', '0.261', '0.024']
lst6 = ['0.75', '1.000', '0.498', '0.495']

lstoflsts = [lst1, lst2, lst3, lst4, lst5, lst6]

def jaccard_set(list1, list2):
    intersection = len(set(list1).intersection(set(list2)))
    union = len(set(list1).union(set(list2)))
    return float(intersection) / union

outputlst = []

for i in range(len(lstoflsts)):
    row = []
    for j in range(len(lstoflsts)):
        res = jaccard_set(lstoflsts[i], lstoflsts[j])
        row.append(res)
    outputlst.append(tuple(row))

print(outputlst)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are looking for something like this:

```
outputarray = np.zeros((len(lstoflsts),len(lstoflsts)))

for idx_1, comp_l_1 in enumerate(lstoflsts):
    for idx_2, comp_l_2 in enumerate(lstoflsts):
        print(f"{idx_1=}, {idx_2=}")
        outputarray[idx_1,idx_2] = jaccard_set(comp_l_1, comp_l_2)
```

Using `enumerate()` during a for-loop you have the corresponding index of your outputarray variable.